# ASP session not working in IE8, working in Firefox, Chrome

Tags: asp.net, firefox, internet-explorer-8, google-chrome

I'm trying to get my site to play a flash video the first time, and only the first time, a user visits the site. Currently, I'm using ASP session tags to install a sessionid cookie into the users browsers.

```
<% Session("name")="blah"
Session.Timeout=7
%>
```

This method works fine in FF and Chrome, but IE8 doesn't seem to want to accept the cookie. I've tested it with IE's lowest security settings possible ("Accept all cookies"), but it still does not create any cookie. Is there any other way to make it so that all browsers will take the cookie?

Comment: What does the HTTP response that tries to set the cookie look like?  (Use Fiddler to see).

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a third-party toolbar installed that might be blocking cookies in IE?

You may also want to go to Internet Tools -> Privacy tab, and make sure cookies aren't being blocked there.